# LINKS IN Collapsible Tree in D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, d3.js

I am new to D3 so I want to figure out some of the following things in this tree layout example(http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) .

1. How can I add Names to Links(edges) that is if there is a link from A to B(B is child of A) then show the name of B on link.
2. How can I change the width of the link based on the size given in child, that is if there is a link from A to B and size of B is 50 then the link's width should be 50px.

Please help me solve these problems as i'm not able to understand the way it has to be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For labels, you need to append `text` elements to the link paths:

```
link.enter().insert("text", "g")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.source.x+d.target.x)/2; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.source.y+d.target.y)/2; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.target.name; });
```

You may want to adjust the label positions.

To change the width of the link, you need to set the `stroke-width` attribute of the path:

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.target.size; })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But there's a problem in positioning of the labels. to remove that we have to replace x with y. if this change is done then the position is exactly on the link.  
another problem here is once the labels are formed.. upon the formation of new labels the old labels are not getting removed.
I have tried the remove() function in removing the text but it wasn't working. can you look into that..??

Comment: As I've said, you may want to adjust the label positions. This should be fairly straightforward. Unless you show me the code you're using to remove the labels, I can't really help you.

Comment: var linktext = svg.selectAll("text.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });      
    
   linktext.enter().append("text", "g")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle") 
      .text(function(d) { return d.target.size; });
   
 linktext.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .text(function(d) { return d.target.size; })
      .remove();

Comment: Did you assign the `link` class to the `text` elements?

Comment: yes I have assigned the Class and also tired without doing that also..
but no change in the problem.

Comment: Did you check whether the selection contains what you think it should contain?