# Add labels to edges of a tree

Tags: javascript, svg, graph, d3.js, tree

I've just started learning `d3.js` and soon enought - bumped into a problem.

Anyway, I need some tree visualization like shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033). I just want to add some labels to the links. More precisely, I would like the tree to look something like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

EDIT: So far, I've tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503905/links-in-collapsible-tree-in-d3-js?answertab=active#tab-top). In the function `update` I put the following code (the code is between the update of the links and entering them):

```
// Enter labels to links
link.enter().insert("text", "g")
    .attr("source-dest", function (d) { return d.source['name'] + "-" + d.target['name']; }) 
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
    .text(function(d) { return "test" });
```

The idea here would be to put a label "test" near each node, and after that to play around with the coordinates until I find the ones I like best. So, instead of putting the labels like I explained, I got them like this:

[image]

Any idea of why the coordinates are behaving like this?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503905/links-in-collapsible-tree-in-d3-js) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344504/how-to-add-label-to-edges-in-d3-graph).

Comment: On the first question - the positioning of the nodes is really weird. On the second - not only that I don't have the labels, but the links are also gone. Any suggestion for the positioning maybe?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Well could you edit the question to show the relevant code and how it doesn't do what you're looking for please?

Comment: It looks like the example you're using has a transition, so maybe that's the reason?

Comment: I don't know what's the reason, I am just starting with d3, and just want to put some labels on the graph.

Comment: I would recommend starting with a less complex example.